# group by column does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to count how many instances of years I have so for example

```
CREATE TABLE YEARS
(
    ID INT,
    DATE_TO_COUNT DATE
)
```

Let's say we have in table 2014-03-13, 2014-04-20, 2015-01-13, 2016-03-13
I wanna receive something like

```
YEAR    INSTANCES
2014     2
2015     1
2016     1
```

So  I tried DATEPART to pull year from it and I have no idea how to count instances of repeating years

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,DATE_TO_COUNT) [YEARS]
FROM YEARS
```

When I try group by years it says that years does not exists, when i try to group by date_to_count it does not count

Any ideas?

Comment: SQL, the language, doesn't allow you to group by *derived* columns. There is no column named `YEARS`. As for counting - you didn't use a `COUNT()` so why should it count anything?

Comment: Have you looked at any SQL tutorials? Not SQL Server, SQL the language. What `GROUP BY` is, how it works, how it can be used with aggregate functions like `COUNT()` and `SUM()` ?

Comment: Yea I tried, if i would not be in hurry I would not ask. I tied to COUNT(DATEPART(YEAR,DATE_TO_COUNT)) but I will receive 4 and I have no idea how to separate it

Comment: This is a basic query. If you were in a hurry, why didn't you check the documentation? It's a lot faster than posting a question in SO. Reading is faster that random attempts

Answer (score 3):

you can try below simple query for this.

```
select YEAR(DATE_TO_COUNT) Years,COUNT(*) Instances from YEARS 
group by YEAR(DATE_TO_COUNT)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already working answer, but if you want see how to use `DATEPART` in this case:

```
 select DATEPART ( year , DATE_TO_COUNT ), count(*)   
 from YEARS
 group by DATEPART ( year , DATE_TO_COUNT )
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with SQL Server, it's just how SQL works. It would be good if a [SQL tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/) was used before trying to write queries

SQL, the language, doesn't allow you to group by a derived column. There is no `YEARS` column in the table, so it's impossible to group by it. If you want to group by a derived value, you'll have to specify it.

If you want to get any statistics from the grouping, you need to use an aggregate function like `COUNT()` or `SUM()`. Without it, you get nothing. SQL can't guess whether you want to count rows or values in a field.

You can get what you want with

```
SELECT YEAR(DATE_TO_COUNT) AS Year,COUNT(*) As Instances
From YEARS 
GROUP By YEAR(DATE_TO_COUNT)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE #YEARS ( ID INT, DATE_TO_COUNT DATE )

INSERT INTO #YEARS
SELECT 1 ,'2014-03-13' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2014-04-20' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'2015-01-13' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '2016-03-13'


SELECT YEAR(DATE_TO_COUNT) YEAR,COUNT( YEAR(DATE_TO_COUNT)) COUNT FROM #YEARS
GROUP BY  YEAR(DATE_TO_COUNT)

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Answer (score 0):

by using PARTITION BY also we can achieve it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(year, DATE_TO_COUNT)
    ,COUNT(DATE_TO_COUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(year, DATE_TO_COUNT))
FROM YEARS
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple SQL Query using Group By clause.

```
CREATE TABLE tblyears 
  ( 
     id            INT, 
     date_to_count DATETIME 
  ) 

SELECT * 
FROM   tblyears
```

**Sample Data:**

```
ID  date_to_count
1   2014-05-21 18:12:13.177
2   2014-05-16 18:12:13.177
3   2014-05-24 18:12:13.177
4   2015-04-09 18:12:13.177
5   2015-02-10 18:12:13.177
6   2016-01-11 18:12:13.177
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT Year(date_to_count)  AS Years, 
       Count(date_to_count) AS Instances 
FROM   tblyears 
GROUP  BY Year(date_to_count)
```

**Output:**

```
Years   Instances
2014    3
2015    2
2016    1
```